# How to do pattern matching with tuple in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, tuples

I have a problem when trying to type match with tuple.

```
filterSth :: [a]->[b]->([a],[b])
filterSth _ [] = (_, [])
```

It means that when the second argument is an empty list, I don't care the first element of the tuple that I wish to return.
How can I implement this ?

Comment: The question is not clear about what you actually want to do and why you want to do it this way. Maybe there are better and more functional ways of doing what you want. So add the context to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't care about the first element of the tuple and you're sure you won't use it you can return `undefined`, i.e.

```
filterSth _ [] = (undefined, [])
```

Remember that trying to evaluate `undefined` will result in a runtime exception.

Another idea might be to return `Either ([a], [b]) [b]` instead.

```
filterSth :: [a] -> [b] -> Either ([a], [b]) [b]
filterSth _ [] = Right []
-- and a case for a non-empty second argument
```

If you want to return the first argument unchanged you cannot use `_`. `_` means that you don't care what's the value of the argument and you're not going to use it. Since you *are* going to use it you have to replace `_` with a named argument and explicitly return it

```
filterSth a [] = (a, [])
```

Comment: er...what if I just want it to remain the same as what I have sent in ?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care what you return as the first component of the tuple, I suggest you return an error that will blow up if you accidentally use it.

```
filterSth _ [] = (error "Don't use this", [])
```

Comment: yeah...it seems that even if I don't care, someone else cares ~~ I will try to avoid such things ~ thanks for your comment ~